# std::vector of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

Continuing with my computer vision stuff I get to a point where I am computing descriptors for one patch in N cameras.
The problem is when I do the computation of the descriptor the function in OpenCV is

```
descriptor.compute(image, vecKeypoints, matDescriptors);
```

where **vecKeypoints** is a vector of `cv::KeyPoints` and **matDescriptors** is a `cv::Mat` that, according to OpenCV's doc it gets populated with the computed descriptors.

As I have N cameras, I compute several descriptors per camera, so I am storing K descriptors per each of the N cameras. Therefore I created an vector of descriptors (i.e. matrices)

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> descriptors;
```

At each iteration I compute a new **matDescriptors** and push it to the vector `descriptors`. The problem I'm seeing is that the address where the data is stores for each of the **matDescriptors** is the same for every element in the vector **descriptors**

As far as I know, when I do `vector.push_back(arg)` a copy of the arg is made and stored in the vector, then, why am I having the same address? Shouldn't `&(descriptors[0].data)` be different than `&(descriptors[1].data)`?

Heres a general view of the code

```
std::vector<Pixel> patchPos;
std::vector<Pixel> disparityPatches;

//cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> descriptor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("ORB");
cv::ORB descriptor(0, 1.2f, 8, 0);
std::vector<cv::Mat> camsDescriptors;
std::vector<cv::Mat> refsDescriptors;

uint iPatchV = 0;
uint iPatchH = 0;

// FOR EACH BLOCK OF PATCHES (there are 'blockSize' patches in one block)
for (uint iBlock = 0; iBlock < nBlocks; iBlock++)
{
    // FOR EACH PATCH IN THE BLOCK
    for(uint iPatch = iBlock*blockSize; iPatch < (iBlock*blockSize)+blockSize; iPatch++)
    {
        // GET THE POSITION OF THE upper-left CORNER(row, col) AND
        // STORE THE COORDINATES OF THE PIXELS INSIDE THE PATCH
        for (uint pRow = (iPatch*patchStep)/camRef->getWidth(), pdRow = 0; pRow < iPatchV+patchSize; pRow++, pdRow++)
        {
            for (uint pCol = (iPatch*patchStep)%camRef->getWidth(), pdCol = 0; pCol < iPatchH+patchSize; pCol++, pdCol++)
            {
                patchPos.push_back(Pixel(pCol, pRow));
            }
        }

        // KEYPOINT TO GET THE DESCRIPTOR OF THE CURRENT PATCH IN THE REFERENCE CAMERA
        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> refPatchKeyPoint;
        //          patchCenter*patchSize+patchCenter IS the index of the center pixel after 'linearizing' the patch
        refPatchKeyPoint.push_back(cv::KeyPoint(patchPos[patchCenter*patchSize+patchCenter].getX(),
                                                patchPos[patchCenter*patchSize+patchCenter].getY(), patchSize));

        // COMPUTE THE DESCRIPTOR OF THE PREVIOUS KEYPOINT
        cv::Mat d;
        descriptor.compute(Image(camRef->getHeight(), camRef->getWidth(), CV_8U, (uchar*)camRef->getData()),
                           refPatchKeyPoint, d);
        refsDescriptors.push_back(d); // This is OK, address X has data of 'd'

        //FOR EVERY OTHER CAMERA
        for (uint iCam = 0; iCam < nTotalCams-1; iCam++)
        {
            //FOR EVERY DISPARITY LEVEL
            for (uint iDispLvl = 0; iDispLvl < disparityLevels; iDispLvl++)
            {
                ...
                ...

                //COMPUTE THE DISPARITY FOR EACH OF THE PIXEL COORDINATES IN THE PATCH
                for (uint iPatchPos = 0; iPatchPos < patchPos.size(); iPatchPos++)
                {
                    disparityPatches.push_back(Pixel(patchPos[iPatchPos].getX()+dispNodeX, patchPos[iPatchPos].getY()+dispNodeY));
                }
            }

            // KEYPOINTS TO GET THE DESCRIPTORS OF THE 50.DISPAIRED-PATCHES IN CURRENT CAMERA
            ...
            ...
            descriptor.compute(Image(camList[iCam]->getHeight(), camList[iCam]->getWidth(), CV_8U, (uchar*)camList[iCam]->getData()),
                               camPatchKeyPoints, d);
            // First time this executes is OK, address is different from the previous 'd'
            // Second time, the address is the same as the previously pushed 'd'
            camsDescriptors.push_back(d);

            disparityPatches.clear();
            camPatchKeyPoints.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mat is some kind of smart pointer for the pixels, so Mat a=b will have shared pixels for a and b. similar situation for push_back()

if you need a 'deep copy', use Mat::clone()

Answer (score 4):

cv::Mat implicitly shares data, so any time you copy it using the assignment operator or the copy constructor, used by push_back in your code, the data is not copied but shared with the new object. Any changes to the data in one will be reflected in the other. In fact, as you have observed, the pointers are the same.

In this case you just need to create a new cv::Mat for every iteration:

```
for (...) {
    cv::Mat d;
    descriptor.compute(..., d);
    camsDescriptors.push_back(d);
}
```

The answer I was searching for, is if you want to pre-allocate the matrices, here is the way to do it without copies, temporaries, or accidental sharing:

```
std::vector v;
v.reserve(N);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // Uninitialized Mat of specified size, header constructed in place
    v.emplace_back(height, width, CV_8UC1);
}
```

Compare this to two efficient looking but **subtly wrong** ways to do this, that look like common C++ code when used with non-shared data structures:

```
std::vector v;
v.resize(N, cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1));
```

or

```
std::vector v;
v.reserve(N);
cv::Mat temp(height, width, CV_8UC1);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // Uninitialized Mat of specified size, header copied from temp
    v.push_back(temp);
}
```

In both these cases the data will be shared behind the scenes between all elements of the vector, which is not at all what we want when creating a vector!

Answer (score 0):

At every loop, make sure to call the function cv::Mat::release() before attaching to the vector.